# GitHub Authentication using PAT

Tags: linux, git, github, token

All this while I have been using username and password while pushing my changes to github. But from Aug 13 2021, github will no longer accept password based authentication and hence I have to use Personal Access Tokens. I have couple of questions regarding this:

1. Do I need to make any changes to my previous repos which were pushed using password?
2. What are the next steps that I need to do after creating PAT, if there are any? should I just use it the next time I am pushing a repo or is there more to it?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dt97iXcNWq4

Answer (score 0):

The change to personal access tokens doesn't affect data that's already pushed.  It only affects new attempts to push, so all of your old code should be fine.

Because a personal access token is pseudorandomly generated and hard to remember, if you haven't already, you should set up a credential manager.  On Linux, that's usually the `libsecret` credential helper.  If your distro has it packaged, install it, and then the next time you're prompted for your username and password, enter your username and PAT instead.  Then it will be saved for the future.

On Debian and Ubuntu, the `libsecret` credential helper isn't packaged, and you'll need to copy the contents of `/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/credential/libsecret` into a temporary directory, install the `libsecret-1-dev` and `build-essential` packages, and then run `make` in that directory.  Then copy the `git-credential-libsecret` binary into someplace in `PATH`, such as `~/bin` (if you have such configured).

Note that if you're working on a Linux system without a desktop environment, then the `libsecret` credential helper won't work, and you may wish to use an SSH key and SSH remotes instead.